# How to trigger a function that emits a livedata object?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

Here is my `ViewModel` code

```
private val logoutRequest = MutableLiveData<String>()

 // observing this livedata in activty

 val logoutUser = logoutRequest.switchMap {
        liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.loading(data = null))
            try {
                emit(Resource.success(data = mainRepository.logout()))
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                val errorMessage = BaseUtils.getError(exception)
                emit(Resource.error(data = null, message = errorMessage))
            }
        }
    }
    

    //calling this function from activity

    fun logoutCall(request: String = "logout") {
        logoutRequest.value = request
    }
```

I am calling logout `API` from main activity and observe that `LiveData` in that activity. But I don't want to trigger `switchmap` from logoutrequest livedata. I want to trigger switchmap automatically when logoutCall is called. Any workaround?

Comment: What is the difference between triggering the switch map from the `logoutRequest` LiveData vs. from `logoutCall()`? You're already doing both. `logoutCall()` changes `logoutRequest`, which will trigger the switchMap function. What are you trying to avoid happening? But is `logoutRequest` used for anything else? If not, this is a convoluted design.

Comment: @Tenfour04 We are trigering switchmap from logoutCall() because this function called when we click button. but i think logoutRequest is unnecessary here. How can we simplify this?

Comment: So you’re asking if there’s a way to consolidate the two properties into one and get the same behavior?

Comment: Yes how we can remove logoutRequest?